# .net 6 Async HttpClient requests to different sites results in multiple duplicate responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm still learning and would appreciate some helpful direction on this problem.

I am trying to use the HttpClient to get the HTML from every website in a list (to get the Open Graph data). I use a nuget package called angle sharp to get the "og:title" content then return all the titles.

I am getting a bug where duplicates are being returned in my response list. There just seems like a lot of unknown unknowns to me right now.

here is the program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
var app = builder.Build();

using
    var sampleBirdsFile = File.OpenRead("sample data/birds_sample.json");

var jsonBirds = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Bird>>(sampleBirdsFile);

var service = new BirdDataService(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>());

app.MapGet("/birds", async () => await service.GetAllDataAsync(jsonBirds));

app.Run();
```

and the BirdDataService class

```
public class BirdDataService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public BirdDataService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetDataFromHtmlAsync(string html)
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default;
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        
        var doc = await context.OpenAsync(request => request.Content(html));
        var selector = doc.QuerySelectorAll("meta[property=\"og:title\"]").FirstOrDefault();
        
        return selector?.GetAttribute("content") ?? string.Empty;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllHtml(IEnumerable<Bird> birds)
    {
        var allHtml = birds.Select(GetHtml);
        return await Task.WhenAll(allHtml);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetHtml(Bird bird)
    {
        var url = $"https://ebird.org/species/{bird.SpeciesCode}";

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        // using var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        return response;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllDataAsync(IEnumerable<Bird> birds)
    {
        var allHtml = GetAllHtml(birds).Result;
        var getBirdDataTasks = allHtml.Select(GetDataFromHtmlAsync);

        return await Task.WhenAll(getBirdDataTasks);
    }
}
```

The response I get when calling the API always looks like this but the number of duplicates and the type of bird is different each time.

```
[
  "Great Blue Heron - eBird",
  "Great Blue Heron - eBird",
  "Great Blue Heron - eBird",
  "Great Blue Heron - eBird",
  "Great Blue Heron - eBird",
  "Great Blue Heron - eBird",
  "Downy Woodpecker - eBird",
  "Hairy Woodpecker - eBird",
  "Eastern Wood-Pewee - eBird",
  "Eastern Kingbird - eBird",
  "Red-eyed Vireo - eBird",
  "Blue Jay - eBird",
  "American Crow - eBird",
  "Tufted Titmouse - eBird",
  "Carolina Wren - eBird",
  "European Starling - eBird",
  "Gray Catbird - eBird",
  "American Robin - eBird",
  "House Finch - eBird",

... more
```

However, when I use `using var client = new HttpClient();` in the GetHtml method, it works and returns no duplicates. I know that is not the correct way to use HttpClient though.

EDIT: I wanted to add that the output in the terminal lists all the requests made to every URL in the sample data with no multiple requests to the same URL.

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://ebird.org/species/cangoo
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://ebird.org/species/cangoo
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://ebird.org/species/mallar3
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://ebird.org/species/mallar3
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://ebird.org/species/chiswi
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://ebird.org/species/chiswi
...more
```

Any help on what I should be looking for to fix this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: `I know that is not the correct way to use HttpClient though.` - [no longer true in .NET 6](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core).

Comment: Sharing `HttpClient` instances shouldn't cause duplicate data, though. Are you sure the URLs aren't duplicated, or contain duplicate data?

Comment: Thanks for the link about HttpClient. I'm pretty sure the URLs aren't duplicated because the logs in the terminal output have each URL listed when the request starts. The final response list is also different every time. It is a different bird title that is multiplied and in different amounts. I wonder if it has anything to do with the rate at which the requests are being made.

Comment: I had weird bugs using `IEnumerable` and Linq, while never turning it into an actual collection. Maybe you should  (at least) deserialize to a concrete type,  e.g. `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Bird>>`.